# Change background color of different website in single iframe

Tags: php, html, session, iframe, session-variables

In parent frame, there are three links (of different website - subdomains) and one button which opens a modal window. iframe has a default website, but the website changes whenever any link is clicked. I want to change the background color in iframe with the help of modal window, such that when any option in modal window is selected and submitted, it changes the background color of website in iframe.

I tried doing it with session variable but able to change background color only of default website.

Please suggest some ways to do it for all the website in single iframe.

Update:

In main.php file:

```
<iframe src="https://www.try1.com?bkg_color=<?php echo $_SESSION['bkg_color']; ?>" name="box" id="box">
</iframe>
```

Links for iframe:

```
<a href="https://www.try1.com" target="box">Link1</a>
<a href="https://www.try2.com" target="box">Link2</a>
<a href="https://www.try3.com" target="box">Link3</a>
```

Form:
There is a button in parent window, when clicked, pops up a modal window and user select option from the drop down list. After selecting, user clicks submit button.

Submit Button:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['bkg_color'] = $_GET['bkg_color'];

}
?>
```

Comment: @kebs edited the question with code.